# When featured tag is auto removed by Community, there is no edit summary

Tags: feature-request, bug, revisions-list, edit-summary, featured-tag

Just noticed this: ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/291741/revisions))

> [image]

It is not hard to understand that the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag has been auto removed by Community, but I still expect some sort of edit summary, even the generic "edited tags". Ideally, it will actually explain the edit, e.g. "featured tag expired".

Comment: Is there any post explaining how this feature (auto removing tags by Community user) works?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I don't think so. It's mentioned in several places the featured tag can be set to auto expire, so it's pretty much only common sense to conclude that it means that once it "expires", the actual removal is attributed to the Community user.