# Explanation of [featured] tag auto removing by Community user

Tags: support, tags, community-user, moderator-tags, featured-tag

Recently I learned that the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag can be auto removed by the [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) user.

[When featured tag is auto removed by Community, there is no edit summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296592/339911)

I would like to know how this feature works. I.e. what are conditions that lead to removing the tag by Community from the question (regular timeout/creation of new questions with [featured] tag/...) ?